# it is possible to use the geolocation in the background sending the current latitude and longitude with a "setInterval" in IONIC1?

Tags: ionic-framework

Basically I want to make a web request in second plane (for example when the cell phone is blocked, or not being used) every 4 hours to a web service that receives the current latitude and longitude. is this possible?

I have researched a lot, and apparently there is no way to do this, unless a plugin is used that detects movement and activates geolocation. for example:

https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation

my client wants the idea that every 4 hours a web service is consumed that receives the current latitude and longitude and verify the stores that are nearby in the current place

Comment: which version of ionic? and your question is not clear. can make your question clear?

Comment: watch location change and send it web server, also possible in background.

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari my version is IONIC1

Answer (score 0):

try this inside your function

```
let config = {
    desiredAccuracy: 0,
    stationaryRadius: 20,
    distanceFilter: 10,
    debug: true,
    interval: 2000 // Set the interval to your desired time.
  };

  this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config).subscribe((location) => {

    console.log('BackgroundGeolocation:  ' + location.latitude + ',' + location.longitude);

    // Run update inside of Angular's zone
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.lat = location.latitude;
      this.lng = location.longitude;
    });

  }, (err) => {

    console.log(err);

  });

  // Turn ON the background-geolocation system.
  this.backgroundGeolocation.start();
```